# How to extract data after groupBy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to extract "left" and "right" data from `pandas.core.series.Series`

This is my test CSV:

```
"A","B","C"
1,1,"Hello"
2,1,"World"
3,2,"Good"
4,1,"!"
5,3,"Good"
6,2,"Morning"
7,3,"bye"
```

And here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
data = df[["B", "C"]]

groupedData = data.groupby('B')['C'].apply(list)
```

Now I have result in `groupedData` and it's look like:

```
print(type(groupedData)) #<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
print(groupedData)

# Result:
B
1    [Hello, World, !]
2      [Good, Morning]
3          [Good, bye]
Name: C, dtype: object
```

When I am trying to iterate through data and extract "left" and "right" part with:

```
for b, c_list in groupedData:
    print(b, c_list)
```

I am getting an exception:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

So how should I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`groupedData` is a series, so maybe

```
for b, c_list in groupedData.iteritems(): print(b, c_list)
```

Output:

```
1 ['Hello', 'World', '!']
2 ['Good', 'Morning']
3 ['Good', 'bye']
```

On the other note, `b` part is called the index, which you can access with

```
for b in groupedData.index: print(b)
```

and `c_list` you can just do:

```
for c_list in groupedData: print(c_list)
```

Comment: Another option is enumerate: `for b, c_list in enumerate(groupedData)`

Comment: @It_is_Chris no, that wouldn't return `b` as the index. For example, it would return `b` starting from `0`.

Comment: I am sorry, you are correct. That is what happens when you do not test before commenting.

Answer (score 0):

When you apply list you got a series in return, so you should do the following

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
data = df[["B", "C"]]

#Here, we returning a pandas.core.series.Series
#So we need to know how to iterate it
groupedData = data.groupby('B')["C"].apply(list)

for idx, value in groupedData.items():
    print(idx, value)

1 ['Hello', 'World', '!']
2 ['Good', 'Morning']
3 ['Good', 'bye']
```